# BIRT Runtime 4.6.0 Error when running genReport

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, birt

I am very new to BIRT. I am trying to run the BIRT sample in **command prompt** that comes with [BIRT Runtime](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/#runtime). I have JDK and JRE installed properly on my computer:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

In the **runtime_readme.txt** inside the Birt Runtime root folder it says:

```
In order to run the BIRT engine in command you should:

1. set BIRT_HOME to the directory where BIRT Report Runtime Package is extracted.
2. enter into $BIRT_HOME/ReportEngine folder.
2. generate the report by run 
    genReport xxx.rptdesign
```

I've set **BIRT_HOME** in my system environment variables to: **C:\birtruntime**

So with that set accordingly (BIRT_HOME set to **C:\birtruntime**), I run into this problem when executing **genReport:**

```
C:\Users\Dylan>%BIRT_HOME%\ReportEngine\genReport "samples\hello_world.rptdesign"

C:\Users\Dylan>ECHO off
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature  file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have looked at many forums online and I cannot find a solution to the above problem. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Attached below is **genReport.bat:**

```
ECHO off

REM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.impl.ReportRunner Usage:
REM --mode/-m [ run | render | runrender] the default is runrender
REM for runrender mode:
REM      we should add it in the end <design file>
REM      --format/-f [ HTML \| PDF ]
REM      --output/-o <target file>
REM      --htmlType/-t < HTML \| ReportletNoCSS >
REM      --locale /-l <locale>
REM      --parameter/-p <"parameterName=parameterValue">
REM      --file/-F <parameter file>
REM      --encoding/-e <target encoding>
REM
REM Locale: default is english 
REM parameters in command line will overide parameters in parameter file
REM parameter name cant include characters such as \ ', '=', ':'
REM
REM For RUN mode:
REM      we should add it in the end<design file>
REM      --output/-o <target file>
REM      --locale /-l <locale>
REM      --parameter/-p <parameterName=parameterValue>
REM      --file/-F <parameter file>
REM
REM Locale: default is english
REM parameters in command line will overide parameters in parameter file 
REM parameter name cant include characters such as \ ', '=', ':' 
REM
REM For RENDER mode:
REM     we should add it in the end<design file>  
REM     --output/-o <target file>
REM     --page/-p <pageNumber>
REM     --locale /-l <locale>
REM
REM Locale: default is english 
IF not "%BIRT_HOME%" == "" GOTO runBirt
ECHO "Please set BIRT_HOME first."
GOTO end  
:runBirt


SET java.io.tmpdir=%BIRT_HOME%\ReportEngine\tmpdir
SET org.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath=%java.io.tmpdir%\workspace_dtp

IF not exist %java.io.tmpdir% mkdir %java.io.tmpdir%
IF not exist %org.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath% mkdir %org.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath%

REM set the birt class path.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


SET BIRTCLASSPATH=%BIRT_HOME%\ReportEngine\lib\*;


REM set command 
SET JAVACMD=java
set p1=%1
set p2=%2
set p3=%3
set p4=%4
set p5=%5
set p6=%6
set p7=%7
set p8=%8
set p9=%9
shift
set p10=%9
shift
set p11=%9
shift
set p12=%9
shift
set p13=%9
shift
set p14=%9
shift
set p15=%9
shift
set p16=%9
shift
set p17=%9
shift
set p18=%9
shift
set p19=%9

%JAVACMD% -cp "%BIRTCLASSPATH%" -DBIRT_HOME="%BIRT_HOME%\ReportEngine" org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner %p1% %p2% %p3% %p4% %p5% %p6% %p7% %p8% %p9% %p10% %p11% %p12% %p13% %p14% %p15% %p16% %p17% %p18% %p19%

:end
```

Comment: You did not mention what research you did. If you haven't already done so, Google `SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes` -- There are quite a few hits and one of them might resolve your problem.  There are several hits on SO, but I can't tell if this is a dup so I'm not going to dup-hammer the question.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison. I've already googled the problem with that SecurityException. All of the advice I found speaks about a change to a Manifest file (unrelated to BIRT, related to the question that was being asked) that is needed. Being very new to BIRT as well as JAVA. I have no idea where or what BIRT's manifest file is or how to change it.

Comment: How about http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/30580-birt-431a-invalid-jar-file-signature/

Comment: Run `jarsigner -verify "org.eclipse.birt.runtime-x.x.x.jar"` (where `x.x.x` matches your jar file).  If it fails you have a corrupted jar.

Comment: @JimGarrison I came across that thread earlier this morning and I ran `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin>jarsigner -verify "C:\birtruntime\ReportEngine\lib\org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar"
jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes` Thanks for the help.

Comment: So that means I should look into fixing the org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar file?

Comment: @JimGarrison I downloaded an archived version (4.2.2) of BIRT Runtime and ran the genReport with no issues at all. It seems that there is a problem with their current release and it also seems I'm not the only one running into this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can say that I have the same error with BIRT 4.6.0. This error did not occur with the BIRT versions I used so far: 3.7.1, 3.72, 4.2.1, 4.3.0. My workaround was to remove all the signature-related files from the META-INF folder inside the org.eclibse.birt.runtime_*.jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Please check - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497356#c1

Remove from the META-INF folder of org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar following files:

ECLIPSE_.RSA

ECLIPSE_.SF

Answer (score 0):

in folder /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib:

```
> sudo zip -d org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA 
> sudo zip -d org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.6.0-20160607.jar META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF 
> sudo zip -d org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.5.0.201603142002.jar META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA 
> sudo zip -d org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.5.0.201603142002.jar META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF
```

It will delete the files that prevent tomcat from deploying the birt.war file

source : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1078982/